# Scala Spark DataFrame Map Encoder non-primitive type

Tags: scala, apache-spark, dataframe, rdd

I have a Scala Spark DataFrame (Variable `df`):

```
id, values
"a", [0.5, 0.6]
"b", [0.1, 0.2]
...
```

I am trying to make use of [RowMatrix](https://databricks.com/blog/2014/10/20/efficient-similarity-algorithm-now-in-spark-twitter.html) to calculate pairwise cosine similarity efficiently.

```
final case class dataRow(id: String, values: Array[Double])

val rows = df.as[dataRow].map {
  row => {
        Vectors.dense(row.values)
    }
}.rdd
```

I am having the following compilation error

```
Unable to find encoder for type stored in a Dataset.  Primitive types (Int, String, etc) and Product types (case classes) are supported by importing spark.implicits._
```

Eventually, I would be able to do this (RowMatrix requires an RDD[Vector])

```
val mat = new RowMatrix(rows)
```

I have already imported spark.implicits_, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Does the `id` matter in any way? Note that `RowMatrix` will not keep the order between the rows, if that is important use `IndexedRowMatrix` instead.

Comment: @Shaido You're right, I do need the id so that I can identify which are the pairs.

Answer (score 1):

There is simply no implicit Encoder for `Vector` types. So either push map after `rdd

```
val rows = df.as[dataRow].rdd.map(row => Vectors.dense(row.values))
```

or provide an `Encoder`

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.Encoder
import org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.encoders.ExpressionEncoder

ds.as[dataRow].map(x => Vectors.dense(x.values))(ExpressionEncoder(): Encoder[Vector])
```

Answer (score 0):

Which Vectors object are you using?

Try importing the linalg context. There might be conflicts within the libraries.

Also move the case class domain object outside of your function scope and then remove final

```
import org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg.{Vectors, Vector}
import org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg.distributed.RowMatrix

case class DataRow(id: String, values: Array[Double])


def func(spark: SparkSession, df: DataFrame): RowMatrix = {
   import spark.implicits._

   val rows = df.as[DataRow]
      .map(row => Vectors.dense(row.values))
      .rdd

   val mat = new RowMatrix(rows)
   mat
}
```

Comment: I'm using `import org.apache.spark.ml.linalg.{Vector, Vectors}`. Case class is outside the scope, I am still getting the same compilation error

Comment: Which version of spark are you using? Odd, because your code very much resmbles that of the cosine similarity: https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/examples/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/examples/mllib/CosineSimilarity.scala

Comment: thats exactly what I'm trying to do with this library, except trying to overcome the encoding error.

Comment: @Ivan where do you insert 'import spark.implicits._'? can you show us in your example

Comment: @Ivan I think you can try selecting df and cast "id" as a string, and values as an Array[Double]